# animation for video slider works once, then fails

Tags: jquery, ios, html, function, ios5

I have a video slider, and the videos are supposed to fade in when you click on the corresponding thumbnail. It works when I preview it in chrome, but when I try it on an iPad (iOS5) it stops working after one time.

If I remove the fade(it's actually an animation), it works, and when it's in use, the video still plays, but the div which has it it black. The function is

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
    var numb = $(this).index(),
        videos = ['images/intro01.m4v', 'images/clip2.m4v', 'images/intro01.m4v', 'images/clip2.m4v', 'images/intro01.m4v', 'images/clip2.m4v'],
        myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
        myVideo.src = videos[numb]; 
        $('#myVid').hide();

    $(myVideo).animate({
        'opacity': '0'
        }, 000, function() {

        myVideo.load();
        $('#myVid').show();
        myVideo.play();

        $(myVideo).animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 1000); 

    });
  });
});
```

Do I need to reset it or something? If you can help at all, that would be greatly appreciated as I'm on a deadline and this is the final part.

Basically, instead of fading in it fades to black.

Comment: Have you tried to stop some animation queue like: `$(myVideo).stop(1).animate({` ? - Or tried to use : `$(myVideo).stop(1).fadeIn(400, function{ // callback here` ?
`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just tried it, still no dice. thanks though

Comment: It's strange that this doen'nt work on iPad. I don't have an iPad, so I can't really do any testing, but try wrapping the video element in a div and animate that instead, if that does'nt work, you'll have to look into CSS3 transitions, as that would probably work on iPad.

Comment: @adeneo I hope this does because the problem with transitions is I had to use a pseudo selector, and it only worked once. Unless you know where to point me to solve that.

Comment: If you applied your transitions in CSS, it will only work once. Try setting the transitions on a class, and remove and add that class to the element with jQuery to make the transition work every time.